# Is iPhone enterprise deployment appropriate for distribution to members of an association?

Tags: iphone, deployment, enterprise

I've had a query about developing an app for members of an association and I can't determine from the Enterprise Deployment guide if this is an appropriate method for deploying the app.

Members own their own devices, so can an enterprise app be deployed while allowing the users to continue to use their own Appstore logins?

At any point, do the devices have to be physically connected to a machine running iTunes that is owned by the association or can a provisioning profile be distributed via the web or email? I see that profiles found in certain directories (e.g., ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/) will be automatically installed, so can the profiles and the app simply be emailed to members?

The Enterprise Deployment guide contains a lot of instructions on locking down the device. Can this be ignored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've had a query about developing an app for members of an association and
>   I can't determine from the Enterprise
>   Deployment guide if this is an
>   appropriate method for deploying the
>   app.

Sounds right for the type of deployment you're talking about.  Just be aware if you're have the enterprise developer account you won't be able to do App store deployment with the same account.

> Members own their own devices, so can
>   an enterprise app be deployed while
>   allowing the users to continue to use
>   their own Appstore logins?

Yes, Appstore apps and enterprise apps can coexist on the same device.

> At any point, do the devices have to
>   be physically connected to a machine
>   running iTunes that is owned by the
>   association or can a provisioning
>   profile be distributed via the web or
>   email? I see that profiles found in
>   certain directories (e.g.,
>   ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning
>   Profiles/) will be automatically
>   installed, so can the profiles and the
>   app simply be emailed to members?

You can get the app binary and profile to the members anyway you like.  Snailmail a CD... stick a USB drive on a pigeon... As long as they have access to the iTunes they sync their devices with, they'll be able to install your app.

> The Enterprise Deployment guide
>   contains a lot of instructions on
>   locking down the device. Can this be
>   ignored?

Not sure which guide you're referring to.  Please include link.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I can distribute the binary and the provisioning profile to anybody and have them install it? Do I not have to register the device in some way first?

Comment: That I'm not sure.  I have the normal developer account and not the enterprise.  I know you need the UUID for every device you want to install on for an Ad Hoc distribution I don't know if that's also a restriction for the enterprise distribution.  I would lean towards, you DO have to register the device by getting the UUID.  Again I'm not certain.

Answer (score -1):

You need the devices UDID which is included in the provisioning profile for the app, that allows that device to run the app

Comment: I believe you are wrong. You create an Enterprise Distribution Profile which you distribute along with your app. You don't need the UDID of all of the devices in the company -- only those use for development. Once the user installs the mobileprovision certificate in ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/ they can then drag apps signed with that cert into iTunes and they will sync to the device and run.